# Can we built all magento native app functionalities with GraphQL?

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am working on Inhouse product so I need some good suggestions

- Can I built all basic functionalities of magento app with graphQL ?

Comment: in theory we CAN do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer thoroughly your question, we would benefit from a list of features you need the graphql to perform. Then for each feature,

1. either the feature has already a call in the GraphQl definition that Vivek has pointed out
2. the feature does not appear in the current definition and you need to extends (create you own graphql call) or customise an existing one. I imagine you want to verify you will not have to customise at all..

Now, GraphQl has been within Magento since 2.3 and therefore is relatively new. My experience has been to use a REST API to perform the calls that aren't in graphQl. (when your system is complete, you can review the areas that use an API and refactor these to use graphQl call)

Answer (score 2):

The support for GraphQL in magento 2.3.5 has become quite satisfactory. You can check out all the mutations and queries you can do with the current GraphQL support here - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/

You will also find the tutorials for implementing basic website features on the same page in the tutorials section.